# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rnn_base'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, conda, miniconda

I am trying to run [this](https://github.com/rdevooght/sequence-based-recommendations#trainpy) python code but I will get the following error:

```
import rnn_base as rnn
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rnn_base'
```

the problem is none of `conda install rnn_base` or `pip install rnn_base` can't find any package with name `rnn_base` to install.

Then can you please guide me how I should install this package on my python?

Comment: `rnn_base` is a python file and not a package. Have you tried adding the location of these files to your system path?

Comment: @Nivii1406 thank you so much. it solve my problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following code to your python:

```
import sys
sys.path.append ('C:\\DIRECTORY\\OF\\PLACE\\WHERE\\rnn_base\\FILE\\IS')
```

please note that you should point to the directory, not the file itself. and also use `\\` instead of `\`